# jQTouch disable scrolling, enable scrolling, to disable scrolling

Tags: iphone, scroll, jqtouch

I'm working with jQTouch and I'm using the animations to link to different href #ids on the same page. On some pages I would want to disable scrolling, and others I want to enable scrolling. By setting disabled scrolling onload then enabling it onlick to another id it will work. However, I cannot switch back to disabled scrolling. Any ideas?

function e(){
 document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    }
}

function d(){
   document.ontouchmove = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Turn the move off by the div.  For example:

```
<div id="dont_move">
   <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
   </ul>
<div id="scroll_me">
   <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And then in your script add:

```
$('#dont_move')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#dont_move')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to disable mouse move:

```
   $(document).bind("touchmove",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   });
```